# Checking to see if a string array index is empty C#

Tags: c#

```
if (Deck[0] //All I gotta know is if this has nothing in it. Speficially "")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wow im really good at this.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Aw jees rick");
            }
```

So right now Deck[0] has "2 of hearts" in it, if there's a way to check and see if "" is the entire value that would be fantastic. The idea here is that "2 of hearts" will be removed after it's displayed so I can make sure I don't display it twice and so I thought I would just make it empty and check to see if the index is empty, which is proving more difficult than I thought.

Comment: Check the length property and compare that to your index

Comment: `if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Deck[0])`, or possibly `if(string.IsNullOrWhitespace(Deck[0])`. Or, since you are blanking it, just `if(Deck[0]=="")` or `if(Deck[0]==string.Empty)`. Personally I'd rather set it to null than an empty string, and then it's just `if(Deck[0]==null`

Comment: Just use Length after null.

Comment: Did you consider comparing it to ""?

Comment: What is `Deck` and what is “has nothing in it”? An empty string is not nothing.

Comment: Of course it was that simple. How surprising I didn't think of that. Thanks! Oh my I see a lot of people replied before I could post this. The first comment solved it

Comment: "" is **not** nothing. It is a 100% valid - albeit very short and empty - string. There are actually special function to excluded the "Empty", null and "Only Whitespace" cases for strings. Matt Burland lists them. Note that there is also a difference between the array not having a index, and the index containing null (wich is a acceptable value for all Reference and Nullable types).

Comment: Also note that for learning anything about classes, class and reference behaviors, String is the worst possible choice. It behaves differently from other classes in just about any way. It is actually designed to work more like a value type in most areas. And then stuff like string interning was added.

Comment: @Christopher String doesn't behave like a value type in *any* ways. It's a reference type.  It behaves like a reference type.  In no way does it behave like a value type.  Yes, the existence of interning makes dealing with its references somewhat different than other reference types, but it's still nothing like value types, it's simply unique in that regard (that regard really being that it has literal values in code, which no other reference type does).

Comment: @Servy: String is inmutable like a value type. Uses value equality like a value type. Wich is opposite just about any class: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18714/Comparing-Values-for-Equality-in-NET-Identity-and Mutabiltiy and Comparision are usually the two most important things you need to learn about Reference types. Oh, and string interning can result in Reference Equality when there should *be* no reference equality by normal class logic.

Comment: @Christopher Value types aren't all immutable.  Lots of value types are mutable.  Lots of reference types are also immutable, not just string.  Immutability/mutability is entirely orthagonal to reference/value semantics.  The same is true of how a type computes equality. Any type can override equality operators/methods to do whatever they want.  *Lots* of reference types override their equals methods/operators to provide value semantics; it's not unique to value types.  Neither mutability nor comparison have anything to do with reference vs value semantics.

Comment: What's *actually* important about reference types vs value types is whether a variable of that type contains the value itself or a reference to the value stored elsewhere, and the ramifications of that, because that's the *actual* difference between the two.

Comment: @Servy: The Canonical List of Value types (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types-table). Please specifiy the Mutable ones (except struct, because on that we agree). And nope, using out to work around inmutability is not mutability. Yes, classes can be made inmutable. How many inmutable classes besides string does the .NET Framework have? How often have you written inmutable classes? Is was pointing out this rarity, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @Christopher That's not a complete list of value types. There are an infinite number of them (because users can define their own).  If you want an example of one in .NET, just for kicks, `Point` is a good example, or `Vector`. I write immutable classes *constantly*; I do it as much as I can. If you want an example in .NET, I suppose the whole System.Collections.Immutable namespace is a good example of immutable classes.  And no, you didn't say immutable classes were rare, you said mutability *was an inherent trait of reference/value semantics*, and yet they have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: "If you want an example of one in .NET, just for kicks, Point is a good example, or Vector" Those are structs (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point.aspx). Structs are on teh list. reading helps :)

Comment: @Christopher Yes, *all* value types are structs.  So in effect you're saying, "point me to a value type that does X, except for all value types".  Yes, you were able to provide a list of around a dozen immutable value types (that are all structs, because all value types are structs).  That doesn't mean all value types are immutable, or that immutability is somehow inherent to value types.  It's not.  There are lots of value types that are mutable, and that's because there's nothing inherently immutable about value types.

Comment: @Christopher if we are going to joke about reading comprehension, should we also touch on how its `"immutable"` not _inmutable_?  Servy is trying very hard to explain to you something that you really need to understand

Comment: @maccettura: 14 of the 15 value types are immutable. The remaing one is struct. For wich we **agree** it is not immutable. I never said classes could not be immutable. I said string is odd for being one of the few classes that **is**. If you combine how odd string behaves in comparision (value equality rather then referene as default), mutability (one of the few that is not), and reference equality (seperately assigend strings might be teh same reference thanks to interning) it is a poor class to learn Reference type behavior.

Comment: @Christopher There aren't 15 value types.  There are *an infinite number of value types*.  Again, *all* value types are structs.  Sure, you could say, "these 14 value types happen to be immutable".  The fact that a few specific value types are immutable doesn't mean that immutability is in any way inherent to value types.  It's not. No one has claimed that you said classes couldn't be immutable.  You said that mutability is important to understanding value/reference semantics. It's not. It's *entirely unrelated* to it.  And again, there aren't just "a few" immutable classes.  There are *lots*.

Comment: @Christopher A reference type having value comparisons isn't unusual at all.  Thinking that all reference types are compared by reference *is wrong*.  If you want to understand how comparisons work in C# then it's important to know that every type defines its own comparison operations. *That* is how comparisons work in C#.  It has nothing to do with reference/value types.  Again, the one and only difference between reference types and value types is whether variables of that type store the value in question or a reference to the value stored elsewhere.

Comment: @Servy:  "A reference type having value comparisons isn't unusual at all. Thinking that all reference types are compared by reference is wrong." Then it is really good I never said soemthing that insane. If you think I did, I need a reference.

Comment: @Christopher "If you combine how odd string behaves in comparision" There you go.

Comment: @Servy: You should read up the word "combine" and how it affects the reading of sentences. And the quoting.

Comment: @Christopher So you don't think that that sentence is saying that string's comparison behavior is odd (in addition to saying other things irrelevant to the point at hand)?  If it's not saying that string's comparison behavior is odd, what *is* it saying?  Nothing is odd about how strings are compared.  Just as nothing is odd about it being an immutable class.  There's also nothing unusual about an immutable type re-using values rather than creating copies (since they're immutable).  Those are all very *common* things to see.

Comment: Also since when does "odd" mean exclsuive/impossible? I could find no such defintion in the Wikitionary: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/odd The default behavior of all reference types is reference equality. The default behavior of all value types (inlcuding all struct implementations) is value equality. The cases taht override that are odd. Not impossible. Not unwanted. Just odd. Like this whole argument about a trivial thing (do not try to learn basics of class behavior from string) is just odd.

Comment: @Christopher But it's *not* odd.  It should be *expected* for a type to override its equality behavior any time the default behavior isn't desired (which should be *often*).  You shouldn't just *assume* every type has the default behavior.  You should assume every type has an equality behavior that makes sense for that type, and what that is has nothing to do with whether it's a reference type or a value type.

Comment: @Servy: You seriously want to tell me that classes that do override their Equals function can not be described as: "unusual, occasional, infrequent, irregular, scattered in frequency" when compared to the bulk of all classes the average programm and programmer will use? "You shouldn't just assume every type has the default behavior." Odd has no meaning like "unexpected". So how did you get to that wierd interpration? Please stop usign reinterpret_cast on what I say. I really have no time to argue with you about the basic meaning of words in the english language.

Comment: @Servy: It is really funny that you want to explain to me "Classes taht override Equals for Value Equality are to be expected" when I **literally said that is string is one of the classes where you have to be aware of it in my second post here**. You know, that post you started this whole discussion on?

Comment: @Christopher Most types have no sensible equality behavior *at all*.  Of those that can meaningfully be compared to begin with, virtually all of them have overridden their equality behavior.  The types for whom the default means of equality comparison is the appropriate way to compare them *are extremely odd*, and you will fairly rarely come across them.  This, again, has nothing to do with value/reference semantics.

Comment: This is all because you're asserting that comparison behaviors is related to value/references semantics when *it isn't*.  `string` doesn't "act like a value type".  It acts like a reference type.  It doesn't act like a value type, because it's *not a value type*.  Your assertion to the contrary indicates that you don't understand what reference/value semantics are all about.   You're propagating incorrect information that will greatly inhibit others from getting a proper understanding of what value/reference semantics are about by saying it has anything to do with comparisons or mutability.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164839/discussion-between-christopher-and-servy).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just try:

```
if (Deck.Length == 0)
{
    //empty array
}
```

Comment: Checking an index that does not exist will give an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.  The first two code examples will throw exceptions